# Why does downloading a file produce an EADDRNOTAVAIL error?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to download a file using node.js using the following script:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream("google.html");
var request = http.get("http://www.google.com/", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

and I keep getting the following error on Windows 7:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL
    at errnoException (net.js:670:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:661:19)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

...and the following error on Linux Mint 13:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:646:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:637:18)
```

What is the most likely cause of this error, and how can I resolve it? The url isn't blocked on my network, so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: http://www.toptip.ca/2010/02/linux-eaddrnotavail-address-not.html

Comment: @Brad I'm running this script on Windows 7, not Linux. Is the link still relevant?

Comment: I'm not sure... Sorry, I don't know what would cause that error on Windows.

Comment: @Brad I've tried running the same script on Linux, and I get a different error.

Comment: @Brad I just tested the same script on Linux Mint 13, and I get the error `ECONNREFUSED` instead of `EADDRNOTAVAILABLE`. See the updated post. (What would I need to do in this case to resolve the error?)

Comment: It's mostly your firewall. I tested your program on cloud9 IDE and it works.

Comment: @vinayr How can I allow specific domains to be accessed from the firewall, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/index.html',
  method: 'GET'
};   

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.end();
```

Comment: In order to use this approach more effectively, I'll need to find a way to get the host name, given the URL. Is there any way to find the host name, given the URL?